# Problem adding multiple CNAME records to AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-route53, amazon-ses, cname

I'm trying to verify my AWS domain to use SES and am having problems creating the DNS records that AWS is telling me to add.  I have to create 3 CNAME records but it will only accept 1 record even though there's a tip that says add multiple records on new lines:

```
Error occurred
Bad request.
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name \052.XXXX.org. does not contain exactly one resource record.)
```

I use * as the subdomain name because the root level is not allowed to contain a CNAME record.  If I try to add 3 records using * subdomain I get the following error:

```
Error occurred
A record with the specified name already exists.
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: Tried to create resource record set [name='\052.XXX.org.', type='CNAME'] but it already exists)
```

At this point I'm confused as to how to add these 3 records.  Any help would be appretiated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the dns tag explains: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Comment: Seems like a pretty legalize reason.  I removed the DNS tag so this is purely related to configuring AWS Route 53 now.

Comment: The tag does not make your question off topic. Your question is not a programming question and that is why it is off topoic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If this is not the place to post AWS configuration questions can you suggest a forum for that?

Comment: NM.  Found it https://repost.aws/en/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the record name is the name column and you add 3 of them, each with different names and values.  I was using my domain name as the record name and that was not unique after 1 was added.